# Have there been duplicate IMEI numbers?

Tags: identity-management, imei

Have there ever been reported cases of duplicate IMEI numbers, whether un-intentional or deliberate?

[Link to the Wikipedia description of the IMEI number or International Mobile Equipment Identity number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. There are some IMEI Changer programs on the internet, and on some phones it's possible to change the IMEI.